400 error when calling parameter store from AWS Lambda extension
I have a NodeJS (node 20/esm/x86) lambda and in us-east-1 and I loaded the layer for Parameter Store as found here so: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:177933569100:layer:AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension:11
I can see in my console it is loaded and also shows in my logs as listening on port 2773.
I then make a call - I have tried Axios and Fetch, adding slashes, not adding them, adding version parameters,not adding it and so on. About 50 different configurations and they all return 400
Error dump:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-06-15T01:36:29.993Z",
    "level": "INFO",
    "message": {
        "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
        "name": "AxiosError",
        "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:589:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:531:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)\n    at ke.request (/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:45:41)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at ci (/lib/parameterStore.ts:34:22)\n    at <anonymous> (/handlers/foo/app.ts:14:13)",
        "config": {
            "transitional": {
                "silentJSONParsing": true,
                "forcedJSONParsing": true,
                "clarifyTimeoutError": false
            },
            "adapter": [
                "xhr",
                "http"
            ],
            "transformRequest": [
                null
            ],
            "transformResponse": [
                null
            ],
            "timeout": 5000,
            "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
            "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            "maxContentLength": -1,
            "maxBodyLength": -1,
            "env": {},
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "x-aws-parameters-secrets-token": "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",
                "User-Agent": "axios/1.6.8",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
            },
            "baseURL": "http://localhost:2773",
            "method": "get",
            "url": "/systemsmanager/parameters/get?name=%2Fsomeprefix%2FmytToken&version=1"

        },
        "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
        "status": 400
    }
}

the list goes on...
Policies:
Policies:
  - SSMParameterReadPolicy:
      ParameterName: 'someprefix/*'
  - SSMParameterWithSlashPrefixReadPolicy:
      ParameterName: 'someprefix/*'

Also played around with header token casing - no diff. 400 seems to want to tell me I am formatting something wrong or missing something but hmm...
any idea?
Posts I read:

https://dev.to/aws-builders/a-different-way-of-retrieving-secrets-in-lambda-functions-4g7h
https://medium.com/@ryan.cormack/using-the-parameter-store-lambda-extension-861450fc9bb9


According to the AWS documentation, the AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension cannot be used outside of the handler function.

The extension can be invoked only in the INVOKE phase of the the Lambda and not during the INIT phase.

While top-level await occurs during INIT phase
Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ps-integration-lambda-extensions.html

It appears that this doesn't seem to run as a top level await outside of the Lambda handler which is what I was trying to do. I had to move it in the handler. Not sure why that is though. There is built in caching so probably not an issue.

we have bumped into same issue, with absolutely same stack. Have you found how to handle it?
What is strange, with AWS SDK for JS, SSMClient class, GetParameter command, works

i found an answer why it doesnt work
